# Moving cyrus_imap from old to new problem

Tags: imap, cyrus

I'm moving from a freebsd12 server to freebsd14, cyrus_imapd30 -> cyrus_imap38.
ctl_mboxlist 'dump' and 'undump' are not working for me.

What I've done:
  `ctl_mboxlist -d >mboxlist.tmp`
move this to new server and do:
  `ctl_mboxlist -u <mboxlist.tmp`
and I get:
  `parse error at line 1: '[' or '{' expected`
Ok, google for a while - looks like I need legacy mode:
  `ctl_mboxlist -u -L <mboxlist.tmp`
Now for each line in the file I get:
  `line xx: no partition found`

I believe I have already set these two machines up in otherwise identical fashion.  Each line in the file ends with a tab, which makes me suspect that perhaps there needs to be an additional field in the list?  Can I just hack something into the file to get by this problem?